Does the presidential nominee usually attend the entire nominating convention?
Major-party Presidential nominating conventions in the United States usually last for several days. For the past several decades (since 1968), the presumptive nominees of both major parties have been known well ahead of the beginning of the conventions, and have given a major address on the final night.
Does the (presumptive) nominee usually attend the entire convention, or only the final night (presumably in order to build up drama for the final night)?

Other than giving their acceptance speech, the nominee has very little to do at the convention. There's no reason why they would need to be there other days, and it was a surprise when Kamala appeared on Monday.
